# Center image in html button

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to show a simple button, with an image on it, like this:

```
<button type="button" style="width: 23px; height: 23px; padding:0">
    <img src="Icon_304.png" />
</button>
```

The button looks right in Chrome, but is off a bit in Firefox—it's not horizontally centered, but skewed to the right.  A FF screenshot is below.  How can I get the image to be centered (like it is in Chrome by default)?  I tried adding a margin: 0 to the img, to no avail.

[image: FF Image]

Comment: This isn't really a solution, so I'll just add as a comment.  Around my office, there is a growing feeling that the button tag is just not ideal.  Different browsers render it differently, and different operating systems can as well.  People have been using DIVs instead and using CSS and maybe some JS to apply all the necessary styling to make it look/feel like a button.  The DIV could easily include your image.  I'm not trying to present this as any sort of "best practice", just sharing an idea.

Comment: @Flying Thank you for sharing.  If I were making a public-facing site that's definitely something I'd take a look at; for my more meager needs I think the padding solution from Dutchie will be fine :)

Comment: @Flying - funny, after trying the padding idea below, it seems as though FF is making the buttons much larger than they need to be - how annoying.  Looks like the button tag does leave much to be desired.  Do you have a link to some resources for making buttons in the way you described above?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The best way to do this is not to set the dimensions of the button, but to simply rely on padding. Obviously you should put these styles into a style sheet, as shown below.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/QgTkt/4/

```css
.tallButton {
  padding: 50px 10px;
}

.wideButton {
  padding: 10px 50px;
}

.equalButton {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="equalButton">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/32x32/ff0/000">
    </button>

<br /><br /><br />

<button type="button" class="wideButton">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/32x32/ff0/000">
    </button>

<br /><br /><br />

<button type="button" class="tallButton">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/32x32/ff0/000">
    </button>
```

Comment: +1 - thank you, that works great.  Unfortunately FF is making the button fairly huge.  If I override the size with specific values, I'm back to square one.  Is there any way to get the image centered, and still have the button an appropriate size?

Comment: what version of FF? The buttons display identically in FF 5.0 as they do in Chrome. If you change the padding to `2px` does the size go down to a relatively acceptable size?

Comment: FF6.  I started with a pad of 2, since that gave me a button essentially the same size as my img in Chrome—16x16.  Unfortunately FF is noticeably larger.  I mean, it's not outrageous or anything, but if feasible I'd like to shrink it down to Chrome/IE size.

Comment: I believe adding: `line-height: 0;` would make this answer better. You can see the bottom padding is not quite right because the text height (line-height) is getting in the way.

Answer (score 7):

You can also set absolute position for the image and negative translate, this way you are able to set any size of the button without changing the padding again.

```
.tallButton{
   position:relative;
   width:200px;
   height:200px;
}

.tallButton img {
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QgTkt/292/

Comment: please clarify why   transform: translate(-50%, -50%); is needed ?

Answer (score 5):

Set the image as background image of the button.

```
<button class="enjoyable"></button>
```

```
.enjoyable {
   background-image: url("./icon.png");
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: contain;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x7j4o0uh/1/

Comment: If I need to place image next to button text how to do that ?  background-position won't work in this case.

Comment: @vikramvi While still possible, it might not be "best practice": https://jsfiddle.net/fdcta46g/16/

Basically, you create a space next to the text the size of the image, and then align the background image with it

Answer (score 1):

I threw this together pretty quickly, so it still needs some tweaking, but you can give this a shot... http://jsfiddle.net/GGXaP/3/

This script (using jQuery) handles the user interaction by adding/removing CSS classes as needed:

```
(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.imageButton').hover(function() {
            $(this).addClass('hover');
        }, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('hover');
        });

        $('.imageButton').mousedown(function() {
                $(this).addClass('mouseDown');
        });
        $('.imageButton').mouseup(function() {
                $(this).removeClass('mouseDown');
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Then it's just a matter of setting up CSS to make the button look the way you like.  The one in my example is pretty rough (I'm a "make it work" guy - not a "make it pretty" guy), but it's a start.

Comment: Very nice.  I'll bet 20 min with a designer (not me) would make them indistinguishable.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue on Chrome I just added `align-items : center` on my button.

By default Chrome sets `align-items : flex-start` on all buttons, which aligns all elements inside the button on the left side, by overloading this property the picture inside my button is now centered.

Comment: Note to also add `display: grid`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving height or width to button or image give padding to button so it will align that image to center

```
<button type="button" style="padding:10px">
    <img src="test/images/searchIcon.png">
</button>
```

Comment: But what if we wanted to center an image in a button where we also wanted to preset the height and the width.

Answer (score 0):

```
button {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Inspiration: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49982708/11322237)