# Center image in button with css

Tags: html, css

I want to make a button with an image with this code

```css
.btnWo {
    position: relative;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    height: 150px;
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
}

.btnWo img {
    height: 150px;
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.button-text {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 25px;
    bottom: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    right: 0%;
    text-align: right;
}

.button-text2 {
    bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wo-img">
  <button id="btnWo" class="btnWo">
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/XNKnzLR0/woBg1.jpg">
    <span id="woName" class="button-text">Name</span>
    <span id="woTime" class="button-text button-text2">Time</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

but the image is a bit off to the right, I want it to fully cover the button
I've been trying [padding solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274875/center-image-in-html-button) and [transform solution](https://jonathannicol.com/blog/2014/06/16/centre-crop-thumbnails-with-css/) but it didn't work

Comment: button has default padding that need to be removed

Comment: You can easily track down `padding` / `margin` mistakes using the [Web Inspector](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/) of your browser. _(Right-click > Inspect)_

Comment: thanks for the information, I didn't know about this before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buttons (and other elements) have some default padding, which is why you see the image shifted.

Add

```
padding: 0;
```

to

```
.btnWo {
    ...
}
```

---

Some developers use a technique where the default values of all elements are "zeroed" at the beginning of the stylesheet. This frees you from such problems.

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are willing to replace the `<img>` tag with setting the background of the button. If so then this code works well:

```css
.btnWo {
    position: relative;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    height: 150px;
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: url("https://i.postimg.cc/XNKnzLR0/woBg1.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
    color: #FFF;
}

.button-text {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: 25px;
    bottom: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    right: 0%;
    text-align: right;
}

.button-text2 {
    bottom: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wo-img">
  <button id="btnWo" class="btnWo">
    <span id="woName" class="button-text">Name</span>
    <span id="woTime" class="button-text button-text2">Time</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the image to be changed using javascript by adding an id to the image tag

Comment: you still can by changing the `background-image` style: `el.style.backgroundImage = \`url("${imgurl}")\`;` where `el` is the button element.